# Shape mismatch in tuple component 16. Expected [1,?,?,3], got [1,1,242,640,3]

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm trying to train an object detection model from tensorflow 1 detection model zoo using python, version 3.7, and when I'm executing it throws all these errors. I'm still learning about this so I haven't any idea about how to solve this problem. Have anyone had the same issue about the different dimensions?

I have checked different questions from this web, like looking for 0 height or width into my csv files and things like that, but It seems like that is not the problem.

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Shape
> mismatch in tuple component 16. Expected [1,?,?,3], got
> [1,1,242,640,3]

Comment: Can you share your code please?

Comment: I'm following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SJRP0IRfPj0, It's a bit old, maybe the problem is there, I haven't modified the code from the repository, so apparently the tfrecord or the csv has an extra dimension and I don't understand why. I'm gonna check if the xml_to_csv file is working good and then I'm gonna check the cdv_to_tf, but if these things work fine maybe the problem is in the model I have chosen? I pic the one he uses in the video, faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco, thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I checked my dataset and my csv file. The problem was almost all of the images had the same shape, but 3 of them not. So I changed those images and regenerate the csv files and the tfrecord files and now is running. The thing with the shape mismatch threw me off, but finally that was the problem